# Union iterator for maps?

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

[*Preface:* The associative C++ containers like `std::map` are a bit like micro-databases with just one key column. Boost's `bimap` elevates this to a two-column table with lookup in both columns, but that that's as far as the analogy goes -- there's no "polymap" that generalizes the idea.]

In any event, I want to keep thinking of maps as databases, and I now wonder if there is an iterator (or some other solution) that allows me to do a UNION of several constituent maps. That is, all maps have the same type (or value type and comparator, at least), and I want a single iterator that treats the entire collection as a big multimap (repeated keys are OK) and lets me traverse it in the correct unioned order.

Does such a thing exist, perhaps within Boost? Or is it easy to rig one up? In pseudo code:

```
std::map<K, M> m1, m2;
union_iterator<K, M> u(m1, m2)
for(auto it = u.begin(); it != u.end(); ++it) { /* ... */ }
```

For example, if we had:

```
m1 = { { 9:00, "Check in"}, { 12:00, "Break" }, { 16:00, "Check out"} };
m2 = { { 10:30, "coffee" }, { 12:15, "baked beans" }, { 15:00, "lies" } };
```

then I want the iterator to produce:

```
9:00, "Check in"; 10:30, "coffee"; 12:00, "Break"; 12:15, "baked beans"; ...
```

Comment: I think you need exactly the same type of map for implementing such an iterator, since it would have to dereference to a `std::pair <key, value>` anyway.

Comment: @Nicolas: I'd probably be OK if the containers had different allocators, at least if the UNION iterator were read-only... Of course the value type (recall that the value type **is** the pair, I didn't say "mapped type") and the comparator have to agree.

Comment: Sorry, I misread "value type and comparator" as "key type and comparator", I thought you intended same key and different value types... EDIT: OK! I think as a map as "key/value pair", so I misunderstood. My mistake.

Comment: Note that either the iterator's `++` operator, or an equivalent amount of pre-processing per element, must be `O(log n)`, `n` being "several" (the number of maps). Otherwise you could use it to perform a sort in less than `O(n log n)`. Rigging one up would in effect be to perform an `n`-way merge, which is easy for `n=2` as in the example and a bit fiddly otherwise.

Comment: @Steve: Yes. Maybe "merge iterator" would be a good name, then it could work for arbitrary sorted ranges, not just maps. Do you know of one?

Comment: Does it need to be an iterator? Is copying one map into the other too expensive? You could also use `set_union` with a comparator on the first element of the pair.

Comment: @pmr: copying all the maps together is indeed a possibility. I just thought there might be a "clever" solution :-)

Comment: @Kerreck: no, I don't know of even a 2-way merge iterator.

Comment: @Steve: I'm trying to conjure up something more general that variadically accepts `map<K, T1>, map<K, T2>, ...`, and whose iterators dereference to `pair<const K, tuple<iterator1, iterator2, ...>>`... but it's not entirely trivial.

Comment: Instead of multiple maps (one for each "category" of data), could you have one big map with an extra "category" column? If so, then you could use `boost::multi_index` which should allow you to iterate over the whole set of data.

Comment: @Emile: Yeah, reorganizing my data would work (at the expense of introducing more coupling). At the moment I'm literally just using two concurrent iterators and advance them conditionally on who's next. I just thought there might be a nice packaged solution that wraps all this up into one single interface...

Comment: Bounty is up: I would still love to see a proper implementation of an object that provides iterators to a view of the data that's equivalent to an ordered SQL UNION.

Comment: Perhaps an idea, not sure how viable to your situation this is, would be an iterator that iterates over a list of iterators, that point to the individual maps.

Comment: @SSight: Getting the correct merged order is important, though. Also, the interface should really just be one single, opaque iterator.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but what is the correct merged order?

Comment: @SSight: well, each map is sorted by the key value and iterated in that order. So I want the union of the two maps sorted as a whole. Suppose the first map's keys are 1, 3, 5, and the second map has keys 2, 4, then I want the union iterator to traverse the two as 1,2,3,4,5.

Comment: A very hacky idea: If it's two maps and just two maps: You'd only need the one iterator, and one other variable: The memory address offset number between the first map and the second map start points. Then all the iterator does is a zig-zag walk (you'd need to be careful of out of bounds issue) between the two searching for whatever it is you want using the offset to modify the iterator between first and second. This assumes contiguous memory allocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I [announced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313160/union-iterator-for-maps/7493705#7493705), I have got something pretty cool.

I'm posting it now, because I wouldn't be sure whether I'd be back in time tonight to post it. I *will* be spending a few words in explanation. (in this post)

> **PS.** The includes will be trimmed down (to about 20%); I will probably do some more general work on the code too.

A lot can be said about this code: it is not very efficient, and not very clean (yet). It is, however, nearly infinitely generic and should scale like anything else. All code can be found in a github gist:

- [merge_maps_iterator.hpp](https://gist.github.com/0ab5e14feee52c9cb807#file_merge_maps_iterator.hpp)
- [Makefile](https://gist.github.com/0ab5e14feee52c9cb807#file_makefile)
- [test.cpp](https://gist.github.com/0ab5e14feee52c9cb807#file_test.cpp) - a rather arcane set of test-cases showing off the genericity 
  <sub>(I'm not saying that it would be a *good idea* to have maps keyed with ints and floats (let alone both at the same time) - just showing that it can be done)</sub>

Here is the output of the test.cpp as you can find it:

```
 == input ========================================
{ 2, aap }      { 23, mies }    { 100, noot }   { 101, broer }  
{ b, 3.14 }     
 == output =======================================
     2: aap;
    23: mies;
    98: 3.14;
   100: noot;
   101: broer;

 == input ========================================
{ b, 3.14 }     
{ 2, aap }      { 23, mies }    { 100, noot }   { 101, broer }  
 == output =======================================
     2: aap;
    23: mies;
    98: 3.14;
   100: noot;
   101: broer;

 == input ========================================
{ 2, aap }      { 23, mies }    { 100, noot }   { 101, broer }  
{ 2, aap }      { 23, mies }    { 100, noot }   { 101, broer }  
 == output =======================================
     2: aap;aap;
    23: mies;mies;
   100: noot;noot;
   101: broer;broer;

 == input ========================================
{ b, 3.14 }     
{ b, 3.14 }     
 == output =======================================
     b: 3.14;3.14;

 == input ========================================
{ 1.0, dag }    { 22.0, bye }   { 24.0, Tschüß }
{ 1, true }     { 22, false }   { 24, true }    
{ b, 3.14 }     
{ 2, aap }      { 23, mies }    { 100, noot }   { 101, broer }  
 == output =======================================
   1.0: dag;true;
   2.0: aap;
  22.0: bye;false;
  23.0: mies;
  24.0: Tschüß;true;
  98.0: 3.14;
 100.0: noot;
 101.0: broer;

 == input ========================================
{ 1.0, dag }    { 2.0, EXTRA }  { 22.0, bye }   { 24.0, Tschüß }
{ 1, true }     { 22, false }   { 24, true }    
{ b, 3.14 }     
{ 2, aap }      { 23, mies }    { 100, noot }   { 101, broer }  
 == output =======================================
   1.0: dag;true;
   2.0: EXTRA;aap;
  22.0: bye;false;
  23.0: mies;
  24.0: Tschüß;true;
  98.0: 3.14;
 100.0: noot;
 101.0: broer;
```

Comment: Thank you - I'll have to look at that in detail, but it looks very promising! What's the ordering criterion for the mapped type when the key is the same?

Comment: @KerrekSB: sry can't make the post tonight, I feel like I've been hit by a bus (I swear it wasn't just the C++ :)) I'll post the backgroun/explanation tomorrow. Thanks for the accept/bounty. Much appreciated!

Comment: No worries. I won't have time to look at this till next week anyway. (I am trying to bounty off my unaccepted questions, though :-).)

Comment: This is indeed pretty cool! After precompiling all the headers (takes about 1 minute), this becomes actually usable :-) Say, is there a way to get around `boost::fusion::tie` and instead just have `std::tuple` and `std::tie`? Also, is there a way to print the mapped values of the iterator without karma?

Comment: @KerrekSB First off, I just noticed that the link in my answer was to an old revision of [the gist](https://gist.github.com/0ab5e14feee52c9cb807)... oops. I don't remember what I changed but it's seen 4 revision since the linked one (hope you saw that)

Comment: You could use std::tuple _but_ you'd not get the interoperability with Boost Mpl quite so easily (nothing you can't write from scratch though :)). Of course you can print it without Karma. I'm just lazy that way. (Maybe later today). Also, disable the karma bits and you'll see that compilation times are normal. Boost Spirit is very heavy on the compiler.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I just got rid of the karma dependency (and of the precompiled headers at the same time). Note that karma was _only_ being used for the test runner anyway, but compilation times greatly reduced, so it makes sense

Comment: Ah, this seems to require a recent Boost (not the 1.42 that's part of my Ubuntu). No worries, that's fine. Can I somehow iterate over each `*mit` to extract all the values corresponding to that key?

Answer (score 9):

There is a "polymap": [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).

Comment: I was always under the impression that multiindex just gives you different views on the *first* column, i.e. the key. Am I mistaken? Can you make a proper database as a multiindex?

Comment: Multiple sort orders on one "column" is just one use-case. MultiIndex supports indexing on arbitrary expressions (in fact the notion of "column" doesn't really exist, only the notion of defining keys wrt elements). Check out the [bimap example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/multi_index/example/bimap.cpp), for instance, which indexes on both columns of a pair.

Comment: I see - so you could have a multi-index on a multiset of tuples, each element being one table row, and the index providing access to various columns?

Comment: You can have a multi_index on the tuple type itself (AFAIK, it owns its contents) and define keys wrt elements of the tuple or even multiple elements in a single key via a user-defined key extractor.

Comment: Thanks, that's really good to know! It isn't the answer to my main question, but +1 in any case!

Answer (score 2):

Either copying both `mapS` into a temporary, appending one to the other (in case you can modify them) or using a `vector` as a temporary with `std::set_union` and a custom comparator are the easiest alternative solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would implement thiton's answer:

```
template <class container> class union_iterator
{
private:
    typedef std::pair<typename container::const_iterator, typename container::const_iterator> container_range;
    class container_range_compare
    {
    public:
        bool operator()(const container_range &lhs, const container_range &rhs) const
        {
            return typename container::value_compare()(*lhs.first, *rhs.first);
        }
    };

    std::priority_queue<container_range, container_range_compare> m_range_queue;
    container::const_iterator m_current_iterator;
    bool m_is_valid;

    void add_container(const container &cont)
    {
        add_container_range(std::make_pair(cont.begin(), cont.end()));
    }

    void add_container_range(const container_range &range)
    {
        if (range.first!=range.second)
        {
            m_range_queue.push(range);
        }
    }

public:
    union_iterator(const container &a): m_valid(false)
    {
        add_container(a);
    }

    bool next()
    {
        m_is_valid= false;

        if (!m_range_queue.empty())
        {
            container_range range= m_range_queue.pop();
            m_current_iterator= range.first;

            ++range.first;
            add_container_range(range);

            m_is_valid= true;
        }

        return m_is_valid;
    }

    typename const container::value_type &operator *() const
    {
        return *m_current_iterator;
    }

    typename const container::value_type *operator ->() const
    {
        return m_current_iterator.operator ->();
    }
};
```

It has slightly different usage than `union_iterator<K, V>` but it implements the basic idea. You can expand the constructor to accept multiple maps however you fit, and use it in a `while (iterator.next())` loop instead of a `for (...)` loop.

EDIT: I simplified `next()` by doing all the popping and pushing at once. So now it's even simpler! (One could also expend some effort making it like a STL iterator, but that gets tedious.)

Comment: I haven't read this one in detail yet (but I might add another bounty, if you wish), but does this take advantage of the fact that the component maps are already sorted?

Comment: Yes; in fact, it wouldn't work they weren't already sorted :)

Comment: OK, I'll add another +50 bounty (when I next get 250+ rep) - nobody should go without some bounty :-)

Answer (score 2):

Very simple solution using boost function_output_iterator:

```
typedef std::map< std::string, std::string > Map;
Map first_map, second_map;
... // fill maps
// iterate over maps union
std::merge(
            first_map.begin(), first_map.end(),
            second_map.begin(), second_map.end(),
            boost::make_function_output_iterator(
                []( const Map::value_type & pair )
                {
                    std::cout << 
                    "key = " << pair.first << 
                    "; value = " << pair.second << std::endl;
                }       
            ),
            first_map.value_comp()
    );
```

We can make this solution prettier by using boost::set_union (range version) instead of std::set_union.

**UPD** Updated version use different key/values types:

```
typedef std::map< int, char > FirstMap;
typedef std::map< short, std::string > SecondMap;
FirstMap        first_map;
SecondMap       second_map;

... // fill maps

struct CustomOutput
{
    void operator()( const FirstMap::value_type & pair ) const
    {
        std::cout << "key = " << pair.first <<
        "; value = " << pair.second << std::endl;
    }

    void operator()( const SecondMap::value_type & pair ) const
    {
        std::cout << "key = " << pair.first <<
        "; value = " << pair.second << std::endl;
    }
};

struct CustomPred
{
    bool operator()( const FirstMap::value_type & first_pair, const SecondMap::value_type & second_pair ) const
    { return first_pair.first < second_pair.first; }

    bool operator()( const SecondMap::value_type & second_pair, const FirstMap::value_type & first_pair ) const
    { return second_pair.first < first_pair.first; }
};

// iterate over maps union
std::merge(
            first_map.begin(), first_map.end(),
            second_map.begin(), second_map.end(),
            boost::make_function_output_iterator( CustomOutput() ),
            CustomPred()
    );
```

**UPD2** std::set_union replaced with std::merge

Comment: Yeah. That's simple. Mainly because it doesn't do what the OP asked. This just does a union of two maps. The OP specifically deals with maps that map the _same key type_ to _distinct_ value types. The end result can never be the original map type. I.e. `'merge'(map<K,V1>, map<K,V2>) -> map<K, tuple<optional<V1>, optional<V2>)`. (My answer even allows for inhomogenous (but comparable) key types, and allows the caller to decide how to represent the valuetype.)

Comment: Sorry, I just read the original question.


But this solution can be easly modified for different key/values types support. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Most interesting... This looks way more versatile than I had anticipated. Hmmm. I'll give it whirl after dinner (my gut says the CustomPred ought to have 4 overloads, or a templated operator<?)

Comment: Ok, so as long as keys don't overlap you get some mileage here: http://ideone.com/RBqEnb# (I've added the output in the "input" section, as it won't actually run on ideone). Sadly, the overlapping of keys was precisely the use case here (to match up corresponding entries in different maps).

Comment: Pretty soon when you want to generalize this to work for any map and combine matching elements in `tuple<optional<V1>, optional<V2>>` you'd end up with pretty much what I posted. Anyways, it looks like, for the 2-map situation only, I could have employed std::set_union to my benefit. Thanks for showing me this - +1 stands

Comment: You can fill result map with values of type `tuple<optional<V1>, optional<V2>>` directly in overloaded CustomOutput::operator()s. Like a `get<0>( _ref[ pair.first ] ) = pair.second` in first overloading and `get<1>( _ref[ pair.first ] ) = pair.second` in second. It'll work if keys are compatible.

Yep, you're right. I forgot that set_union eliminates duplicate values. I'll fix it by replacing std::set_union with std::merge. This algorithm save both sets unchanged.

Comment: It _preserves_ them, but doesn't _merge_ the corresponding results, does it? Why don't you add a compiling test case yourself, so I don't have to in order to figure it out? (I think I'm a few steps ahead: next you'll add state into the `CustomOutput` functor so you can add to the same entry if the `key` has _equivalent ordering_. In which case you'll have to track which source map you're visiting as well. Now extrapolate for any key/value type and N number of input maps: this is basically what I wrote.)

Comment: Compile test on ideone.com doesn't compile :) But I checked this code before updating answer, it works properly with duplicate entries in different maps. You can manually merge corresponding values in functors. I don't doubt about usefulness of your solution, std::set_union/merge can't be used for any number of maps greater than two.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20268/discussion-between-sehe-and-maxim-ky)

Comment: Thanks a lot for showing this approach, and also to @sehe for the discussion!

Answer (score 1):

> Or is it easy to rig one up?

Rigging up should be fairly easy: For N base maps, your iterator contains a priority queue prioritized by the N keys of the elements the base iterators point to. For dereference, dereference the iterator at the queue front. For increment, increment the iterator at the queue front and, if it's increment is not at the end, re-insert it.

Comment: Hm, I have to think about this. I can't quite see it, but I might just not be awake enough at this point. Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing very special to understand, it is basically just a merger of sorted sequences using priority queues.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how it can be done quite easily:

```
template<class It>
class union_iterator
{
public:
  union_iterator(It it1_begin, It it1_end, It it2_begin, It it2_end)
     : current1(it1_begin), current2(it2_begin), end1(it1_end), end2(it2_end)
     { if (it1_begin != it1_end && it2_begin != it2_end) {
         if (*it1_begin < *it2_begin) { current= &current1; }
         else { current = &current2; }
       } else if (it1_begin==it1_end) { current=&current2; }
       else { current = &current1; }
     }
  void operator++() { 
    if (current1!=end1 && current2 !=end2) { 
       if (*current1 < *current2) 
         { ++current1; current = &current1; } 
         else { ++current2; current=&current2; } 
    } else if (current1==end1 && current2 != end2) {
       ++current2;
       current = &current2;
    } else if (current1!=end1 && current2 == end2) {
       ++current1;
       current = &current1;
    }
  }
  typename std::iterator<It1>::value_type operator*() { return **current; }
private:
  It current1;
  It current2;
  It end1;
  It end2;
  It *current;
};
```

But the real problem is implementing all the remaining member functions required by normal iterators :-). Boost has some lib for helping you do it, but it might still be quite difficult.

Comment: I would be happier if: `T` wasn't a template (figured out from std::iterator<It>::value_type), the iterators were in a vector/array, and you didn't assume they were map iterators (use `*current1 < *current2` instead of comparing the `->first` directly.  You also check if `current1==end1` many times, which can be avoided via more nested `if`s.  You also use `current1++` when `++current1` _may_ be faster.  Actually, I think you got the only hard operator other than operator< (which probably can't be done).  That all sounds critical, but this answer is what I'd do.

Comment: If you don't access `->first`, then this could also be used on sorted std::vector`s

Comment: unfortunately I think the ->first is necessary because map iterators return pairs. it might need separate version anyway for map and vector -- it really need to choose the first element of the pair for map case.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/utility/pair/ `In inequality comparisons (<, >), the first elements are compared first, and only if the inequality comparison is not true for them, the second elements are compared.`  Magic!

Comment: oh, that's nice. I didn't know about that. :) I'll edit the answer.

Comment: It just dawned on me: make it take _two_ iterator types, and be able to: `union_iterator<union_iterator<std::map<char, int>::iterator>, std::unordered_map<short, int>::iterator>>, std::vector<int>::iterator>`, thus merging _three_, with different (but comparable!) key types!  (You'd need to change `current` to a bool, since they're different types.)

Comment: Also, make sure you have these http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/iterator_traits/ typedefs so this counts as a fully-fledged iterator.

Comment: Nevermind, two std::pairs wont compare if they have different template types.

Comment: The change with currentA/currentB should be revoked, since it (A) requires that iterators be assignable from an integer, and (B) implies that you can compare various iterator types, when you actually can't.  The code won't allow you to merge maps of different types, or maps with anything else.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an iterator like you asked for, but I just found this function in the standard library:

> § 25.4.5.2 set_union [set.union]
>
> ```
>  template<class InputIterator1, class InputIterator2,
>  class OutputIterator, class Compare>
>  OutputIterator
>  set_union(InputIterator1 first1, InputIterator1 last1,
>  InputIterator2 first2, InputIterator2 last2,
>  OutputIterator result, Compare comp);
> ```

1. Effects: Constructs a sorted intersection of the elements from the two ranges; that is, the set of elements that are present in both of the ranges.
2. Requires: The resulting range shall not overlap with either of the original ranges.
3. Returns: The end of the constructed range.
4. Complexity: At most 2 * ((last1 - first1) + (last2 - first2)) - 1 comparisons.
5. Remarks: If [first1,last1) contains m elements that are equivalent to each other and [first2, last2) contains n elements that are equivalent to them, the first min(m, n) elements shall be copied from the first range to the output range, in order.

There's also a `std::set_intersection`, `std::set_difference`, and `std::set_symmetric_difference`